# How to read linkedin inbox messages

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I've done a massive research on linkedin api in order to find out how to read my inbox messages through the [Api](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest).

i've looked in this post where they say that this isn't possible:
 [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/read-messages-inbox)

Did anyone found a good solution/workaround for this issue?

Comment: As you mention, it is not possible using the LinkedIn APIs.

Comment: At the time I was writing this, LinkedIn is developing Message API in their v2 API bundle so that we could use to retrieve and send messages. The API is still coming soon. Here is the link we could look at and know when it's available.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/communications/messages

Comment: You can retrieve Linkedin messages using their [Messages API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/communications/messages?context=linkedin/compliance/context).

Comment: @KristijonasŽibutis with that api we can only create a message and reply to the message right? But I was looking for the list of total conversations of a user. Is this possible to achieve with linkedin api's.