# How to retrieve inbox messages from linkedin Message API

Tags: linkedin-api

I would like to retrieve all messages from Linkedin inbox via API V2.

I Have gone through Linkedin V2 API docs many times, but i still cant figure it out.

I can get profile info with following request through POSTMAN:

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))

How to forge the request to recieve Linkedin inbox messages in respond?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976847/how-to-read-linkedin-inbox-messages

Comment: I saw the thread is 7 years old and i thought i should start new one as V2 API is active just for a few months now.

Comment: [According to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/communications/messages), support for requests such as retrieving inbox messages is "coming soon".

Answer (score -2):

hello bro give your access_token at params as oauth2_access-token="Access Token"

Comment: While there is no problem with your assumption, because OP clearly identfies as, possibly grown up, boy, please skip salutations and try for [answer].